# Start YTPlayerView in full screen on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, youtube-data-api, ytplayerview

I am using YTPlayerView iOS class which is provided by Youtube and you can check it [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

The problem is the following: on iPhone the video automatically starts in full screen while on iPad it doesn't, and I need to start it in full screen by default.

Comment: post the code you have on iPhone that works fullscreen and doesn't on iPad

Comment: Just go to the URL, download the class and the HTML player template, then use the method loadVideoById, that's all

Comment: @AubadaTaljo, were you ever able to fix your issue?  I'm running into the same issues you are.  For me it plays but I can't see the video, only the audio.

Comment: Actually no! still no luck with this issue, I am getting the video but I don't know how to change the player to full screen mode without making the user tap on it, my life is easier than yours I guess

Comment: Hi Guys.. I am also facing same problem. in iPad video play only in normal mode but its working full screen in iPhone. So please let me know solution if you got. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is facing this problem, I solved it by dropping this class and using XCDYoutubeKit, it solved my issue but I had to drop the separate UI where I used my player.

https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit

It's also available through cocoapods

Comment: As documented in the README, this library is expressly against the Youtube Terms of Service.  I would be interested in a solution that isn't. (For those who are interested, see section 4.C of the [terms of service](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms))

Answer (score 1):

Add this code, so on iPhone it will not start to play on full screen:

```
var playerVars: NSDictionary = ["playsinline" : 1]
self.playerView.loadWithVideoId("6v2L2UGZJAM", playerVars: playerVars)
```

Comment: I need the iPad to start playing in full screen, not to make the iPhone video starts in a small screen!!